# How to convert rxJava2's Observable to Completable?

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have Observable stream, and I want to convert it to Completable, how I could do that?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The fluent way is to use `Observable.ignoreElements()`.

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
.ignoreElements()
```

Convert it back via `toObservable` if needed.

Comment: More conversions can be found here. https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/looking-ahead-to-rxjava-2-droidcon-nyc-2016?slide=106

Comment: Note that RxJava 1 does not automatically convert this to a Completable. This functionality is achieved in v1 using `Observable.toCompletable()`. v1's `ignoreElements()` just creates another Observable without elements.

Comment: flatMapCompletable can also help in this situation depending on your needs

Answer (score 18):

You can do something like below.

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
Completable completable = Completable.fromObservable(observable);
```

Like on an Observable, you will have to subscribe to the `completable` to start the asynchronous process that `Observable` wraps.

More details can be found [here in the Java doc for the method](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#fromObservable(io.reactivex.ObservableSource)).

Answer (score 4):

As I understand all this solutions will work only if Observable call `onComplete`, which is not enough if you want your result `Completable` to trigger after first `onNext` or `onError`, so for this case I'd recommend this:

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
Completable completable = observable.firstOrError().ignoreElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Completable.merge(YourObservable()...

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Completable.fromObservable(xx)**. That is worked fine on my project.