# RXKotlin how do you map to void?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

Sorry nooby kotlin question

```
func someThingElse(): Observable<String> {
   return Observable.just("aasd")
} 

fun doSomething(): Observable<Void> {
    return someThisElse().fetch().map { () } 
}
```

How do i return an observable of void?
I tried `void`, `Void()`, `Void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unit` in Kotlin corresponds to `void` in Java. Like `void`, `Unit` is the default return type of any function in Kotlin that does return anything.

Using [`Completable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#completable), [`Single`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#single) or [`Maybe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#maybe) might make more sense though

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent of `Observable<Void>` i.e. Observable that doesn't return any value - only completes or ends with exception - is [`Completable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html):

> Represents a deferred computation without any value but only indication for completion or exception.

Comment: Just an addition: You can use `ignoreElements` to convert an Observable to a Completable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399397/how-to-convert-rxjava2s-observable-to-completable

Comment: `Observable<Void>` does return value of unit type (void) via 0...N `next` events, so it is definitely not equivalent to `Completable`, which does not produce `next` events.